# Wordpress - cleartext admin credentials disclosure

Tags: sql-injection, known-vulnerabilities, wordpress

I am testing my own wordpress blog against security issues with `wpscan`.

Honestly I have never done that before and was shocked after I saw the result.

One vulnerability of my wordpress site is:

```
[+] WordPress version 3.8 identified from rss generator
[!] 1 vulnerabilities identified from the version number
 |
 | * Title: wp-admin/options-writing.php Cleartext Admin Credentials Disclosure
 | * Reference: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/Dec/135
 | * Reference: http://osvdb.org/101101
```

What does that mean? Is it easy for attackers to get admin rights on my site? If so how could sb do such a thing? How can I secure against this?

I appreciate your answer

Comment: Have you checked the links that the error gives you as references.  They do a rather nice job of explaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the references in the warning you put in the question, it explains that the password used for E-mail is stored in plain text in the DB and that this may be disclosed.  It appears to only potentially leak the credentials associated with the e-mail account used to send messages for the forum.